# From XQuery to XHTML

Tags: xml, xhtml, xquery

I would need some help.

I'm trying to write an XQuery, whose output would be an XHTML file. The problem is, that "An XHTML document must have an XHTML DOCTYPE declaration" and I'm unable to put the DOCTYPE line in my XQuery file to generate a valid XHTML file.

I may have misunderstood something, so any help is appreciated.

**More specifically:**

I have a small XQuery script:

```
for $book in doc("data.xml")//book
        where $book/copycount = max(
            for $count in doc("data.xml")//book/copycount
            return $count
            )
        return (data($book/title))
```

And I would like to generate a valid XHTML file around this script which displays the returned string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XQuery processor does not serialize the result itself, you have to tell us more about your platform and how you consume the result.

If your processor serializes the result itself and is 1.0, you have to tell us which one you use and look into its documentation for the implementation-dependent switch to do it.

Last but not least, if you use XQuery 3.0 and your processor takes care of the serialization, you can use the following to tell it to serialize the output tree as XHTML, using the proper DOCTYPE (see the relevant definition in the spec at http://w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-serialization and http://w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-30/#xhtml-output):

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method         "xhtml";
declare option output:doctype-public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN";
declare option output:doctype-system "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd";

/some/query/here
```

Comment: thanks. could you maybe include my script in it (meaning to give an example, how the whole file would look like)? I tried, but my Query doesn't return anything (I think I messed up the namespaces). much appreciated.

Comment: I edited the example above, to include the XQuery version, and where to put your original query.  Note that this is only available in XQuery 3.0.  What processor do you use?

Comment: I got it working. I used the header you included, I declared my query script as a function and in the <body></body> tags I only put the function. Works like charm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

One universal way to do this is by inserting it as text node child of the document node:

```
document {
  text { '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">' },
  xdmp:quote(
    **** your XQY ****
  )
  (: or in eXist, util:serialize(), etc.  :)
}
```

Some XQuery processors have option flags for things like this, so you may be able to use that instead, and let the processor serialize it for you.

Comment: sadly the output is:
"&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC....." and I can't escape the < character

Comment: @Wanderer which XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: Trying to generate the DOCTYPE by hand is a bad idea. The "special characters" (especially `<`) will be escaped by the serializer (unless you configure it properly not to do so, but then, configuring it properly to output the DOCTYPE for you is much better).

Comment: @FlorentGeorges Bad idea for whom? Doctypes aren't typically preserved in documents in databases, and not all processors support XQuery 3.0 in its entirety. For example, this is the only way to accomplish this using MarkLogic. And what if you needed to dynamically construct different doctypes? Not possible in the preamble.

Comment: Since you edited your example, it is clear now that you mean generating serialized output, including the doctype (not trying to add the doctype before the result tree itself).  Which might work, but is not guaranteed (that also depends on your processor).  And if you want to generate dynamically the doctype public and/or system, indeed you have to rely on something processor-depend, as it is not supported in standard XQuery 3.0.  By the way, I would argue that the idiomatic way of adding a doctype in MarkLogic is by using xsl:output ;-)

Comment: @FlorentGeorges That's a fair point. Not reasonable is asserting that is a bad idea. At worst it's as you suggest non-idiomatic; at best it's the only way to accomplish some tasks (and reliably). In fact, I have a similar solution in production for handling doctype dependent apps. It's a pattern MarkLogic implementers have used repeatedly for similar tasks.